# Unable to call the service in application

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, wcf

Hi when iam trying to consume the service in my application it is throwing an error Error   12  The type arguments for method 'Eiss.Core.Services.FloorPlanMethods.ErrorWrap(string, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. E:\Code\WebPlatform\Branch\CodeFin\Presentation\EISS\CoreServiceInterfaces\FloorPlanMethods.cs  48  13  CoreServiceInterfaces

```
 [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(EissError))]
    void ProcessCallHistoryRequestQueue();
```

in Bal

```
public static void ProcessCallHistoryRequestQueue()
    {            
        Aspect.Wrap("CallHistoryRequestQueue.ProcessCallHistoryRequestQueue", new AuditParameters(), () =>{

            // Get unprocessed Queue Item
            var queueItem = DAL.CallHistoryRequestQueue.FetchQueueItemForProcessing();
            Guid fileStoreGuid = Guid.Empty;
```

in dal

```
 public static STO.CallHistoryRequestQueue FetchQueueItemForProcessing()
    {
            return Aspect.WrapSingle("CallHistoryRequestQueue.FetchQueueItemForProcessing", new AuditParameters(), db => 
            db.CallHistoryRequestQueues.OrderByDescending(a=>a.CallHistoryRequestQueueID).SingleOrDefault(sto => sto.IsProcessed == false));
    }
```

in application

```
 public static List<CallHistoryRequestQueue> ProcessCallHistoryRequestQueue()
    {
      return  ErrorWrap ("ProcessCallHistoryRequestQueue", s => s.ProcessCallHistoryRequestQueu()); error here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough detail to give a detailed solution but that error is the result of calling a generic method without specifying a type. Quite often the compiler can work out the type for you but in this case it's ambiguous and it needs you to tell it.